# Filtering logs in Azure Web App Diagnostics Logs

Tags: asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc, azure-web-app-service, asp.net-core-1.0

Is it possible to filter logs using Azure's Web App Diagnostic logs to capture application logs?

I want to capture information-level logs reported from our assemblies, but only warnings for MS/System libraries.

`Startup.cs` looks as follows:

```
loggerFactory
    .WithFilter(new FilterLoggerSettings
    {
        { "Microsoft", LogLevel.Warning },
        { "System", LogLevel.Warning },
        { "MyAssembly", LogLevel.Information }
    })
    .AddAzureWebAppDiagnostics();
```

But in the Azure Portal there is only an option to set the level:

[image: Azure Web App Diagnostics Logs]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to your scenario, I have tested this issue and you could just configure your logger in `Configure` method of `Startup.cs` as follows:

```html
loggerFactory
    .WithFilter(new FilterLoggerSettings
    {
        { "Microsoft", LogLevel.Warning },
        { "System", LogLevel.Warning },
        { "{custom-category}", LogLevel.Information}
    })
    .AddAzureWebAppDiagnostics();
```

**Note:** The category would be the fully qualified name of the class from which the logs are written. If the logger is under `TodoApi.Controllers.TodoController`, you could configure `{custom-category}` as `TodoApi` to limit framework logs level to informations for the logs from your assemblies.

> The Azure App Service provider
>
> This provider is **available only for apps that target ASP.NET Core 1.1.0 or higher**. **The provider only works when your project runs in the Azure environment**. It has no effect when you run locally -- it does not write to local files or local development storage for blobs.

When using Azure App Service Logging, the available log level would be the larger one between the level you set in your filtering rules and the application level your configured on Azure Portal. In order to capture information-level logs reported from your assemblies, the Application Level you configured on Azure Portal need to less than or equal information-level, you could configure it to `verbose` or `information`. For more details, you could refer to this official [tutorial](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/logging#appservice).

**UPDATE:**

Here are the details about my test, you could refer to them:

**Log filtering**

```
loggerFactory
    .WithFilter(new FilterLoggerSettings
    {
        { "Microsoft", LogLevel.Warning },
        { "System", LogLevel.Warning },
        { "WebApplication_FilterLogging", LogLevel.Information }
    })
    .AddConsole()
    .AddDebug()
    .AddAzureWebAppDiagnostics();
```

**HomeController.cs**

```
public class HomeController : Controller
{
    private readonly ILogger _logger;
    public HomeController(ILogger<HomeController> logger)
    {
        _logger = logger;
    }

    public IActionResult Index()
    {
        _logger.LogWarning($"Index {DateTime.UtcNow}");
        return View();
    }

    public IActionResult About()
    {
        _logger.LogInformation($"About {DateTime.UtcNow}");
        return View();
    }

    public IActionResult Contact()
    {
        _logger.LogError($"Contact {DateTime.UtcNow}");
        return View();
    }
}
```

**Result**

1) Logs from my output window:

[image]

2) Logs from my application log stored in Blob Storage:

[image]

When I set information-level logs for Microsoft/System libraries, then I could retrieve the following logs:

[image]

[image]

Comment: This doesn't seem to work. I have set up the level to Information on the Azure Portal and have applied that filter in Startup, but I still get information-level logs for MS and System.

Comment: I have updated my reply and added some detailed info, you could refer to them.

Comment: And in the Azure portal have you selected 'Information' as the log level? Thanks for your thorough answer.

Comment: Yes, I selected information-level for Application Logging (Blob) in Azure Portal.

Comment: Working great. I'm not sure how I got it wrong before.

Comment: This is somehow happening again. On local it will log with the filters applied, but when hosted it logs everything to the Web App's diagnostic logs. I'm pulling my hair out on this one

Comment: I would check this feature again on my side to find whether something could cause this issue.

Comment: I've noticed that the diagnostics tab now prompts me with "Click here to install the ASP.NET Core site extension to enable Application Logging." - what is this and is it necessary?

Comment: In my mind, I just build my net core web application and deploy to azure web app via VS, I do not install any extension on Azure Portal. I think you could try to follow the instruction and find whether it could solve this issue.

Comment: Does anyone have solution for this problem? Because none of provided solutions does not work for me on Azure. Everything is filtered like expected on local. Azure just ignore my appsettings.json

Comment: I opened a GitHub issue for this. I'm having the same experience as Igor ^

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42789154/filtering-logs-in-azure-web-app-diagnostics-logs

Comment: @FranciscoVilches can you drop a comment with the link to your GitHub issue in? I've got this same problem.

Comment: @Jaffacakes82 

Here's the Github issue. It also has a link to the PR. The fix has now been merged to develop. Hopefully will be included in a release soon

https://github.com/awslabs/aws-sam-cli/issues/1970

Comment: @FranciscoVilches that looks like a different issue altogether, did you send the wrong one?

Comment: @Jaffacakes82 my bad. This is the correct one: https://github.com/dotnet/AspNetCore.Docs/issues/15212

Comment: @FranciscoVilches hmm, their change looks like an update to documentation rather than a code fix. Did you ever manage to resolve this? I'm trying to get this working by adding the filters programatically in my Program.cs rather than using an appsettings.json file.

Comment: hi @Jaffacakes82 unfortunately I didn't. I relegating to the fact that "Diagnostic Logs Level is only used for Log streaming output. It doesn't apply to any other logging providers." -Microsoft

I believe I ended up using serilog, and started logging in Program.cs even before the app was bootstraped

Answer (score 4):

You can also apply filters in your appsettings.json file like this

`"Logging": {
    "IncludeScopes": false, 
    "AzureAppServicesBlob": {
      "LogLevel": {
        "Default": "Warning",
        "Microsoft": "Warning",
        "System": "Warning",
        "{custom-category}": "Information"
      }
    },
    "LogLevel": {
      "Default": "Warning"
    }
  }`

There's also a provider aliases for AzureAppServicesFile.

Answer (score 0):

I faced the same issue recently by using below log filters in appsettings.json.

```
"Logging": {
    "LogLevel": {
      "Microsoft": "Warning",
      "System": "Warning",
      "Default": "Information"
    }
  }
```

I had to specify the log levels for each target as given below.

```
"Logging": {
    "AzureAppServicesBlob": {
      "IncludeScopes": false,
      "LogLevel": {
        "Microsoft": "Warning",
        "System": "Warning",
        "Default": "Information"
      }
    },
    "AzureAppServicesFile": {
      "IncludeScopes": false,
      "LogLevel": {
        "Microsoft": "Warning",
        "System": "Warning",
        "Default": "Information"
      }
    },
    "LogLevel": {
      "Microsoft": "Warning",
      "System": "Warning",
      "Default": "Information"
    }
  }
```

Log level in Azure portal was set to **Information**.